# How to use ESPER performance kit for measuring latency and throughput of queries with single row functions

Tags: performance, esper

I have written some ESPER CEP queries that use single row function in the queries.

Now, I want to measure the latency and throughput of the query using the ESPER performance kit.

So I am adding my query in the statement.properties, but I am not sure how and where I should write my single row function. Can I write it in a statement.properties itself? Below is my query with single row function called compute_average

```
Tsinglerowfn = select '$' as  ticker, compute_average(e) from Market(ticker='$')#time(5 seconds) as e
```

How can I measure the performance of queries with single row function in ESPER using the performance kit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add the EPL to the properties. You need to make sure that "compute_avg" is registered as a predefined single-row function in the configuration. For that you need to bring up the IDE as that is not done in the properties file.

If the function computes some kind of average, which is a stateful concept, you should use the aggregation function extension API and not the single row function as that is for stateless functional code.